# Slick2D: Loading: net.java.games.input.DirectAndRawInputEnvironmentPlugin

Tags: java, slick2d

Dears,

I have recently changed my computer and my mouse and I am facing now a very strange behavior. When I try to launch my game (developed with Slick2D) from Eclipse, it fails if my new BLUETOOTH mouse is connected.

Every time I run the game, I have got a black window blocked in an infinity loop and the console is displaying the following message:

```
WARNING: Found unknown Windows version: Windows 10
Attempting to use default windows plug-in.
Loading: net.java.games.input.DirectAndRawInputEnvironmentPlugin
```

If i switch off the mouse, it runs but the console displays the following:

```
WARNING: Found unknown Windows version: Windows 10
Attempting to use default windows plug-in.
Loading: net.java.games.input.DirectAndRawInputEnvironmentPlugin
Failed to initialize device HIDI2C Device because of: java.io.IOException: Failed to acquire device (8007001e)
```

Then, I have got an infinity of the following message:

```
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
Failed to poll device: Failed to poll device (8007000c)
```

But at least, the game started...

Can you please help? Do you know how to solve the problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For those who will have the same problem, I have found the solution. The error arrived when a device is not supported by your library. In my case, it was a new HP Bluetooth Mouse that allow negative coordinates.

How to fix it? Very simple. The problem come from JInput and if you read [the documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/net.java.jinput/jinput/2.0.7/net/java/games/input/package-summary.html), you see that you have to disable the "useDefaultPlugin":

```
System.setProperty("net.java.games.input.useDefaultPlugin", "false");
```

Hope this will help other than me because I lost almost 3 days on this...